# What is my missing SSD drive used for?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

My new asus laptop came with an ssd drive and a normal drive. I was expecting to see the c drive as the ssd but it doesnt even have a drive letter. I assume that its not actually big enough to have the full windows and all program files but that it is still being used somehow? If so what for? What format will it be and how can I find more about this?

[image]

Comment: found this article : http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/12/feature_what_the_best_solid_state_disk_configuration/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used as a cache on for the traditional hard drive. It will cache recently accessed files and enables the speed benefit of a SSD with the storage capacity of spinning hard disks.

See [Intel Smart Response video](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-smart-response-video.html) for more info.

Comment: You can also download the [Intel Rapid Storage drivers](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/sftwr-prod/imsm) to configure the cache and the like, though it looks like ASUS may have a recovery partition on their or something.

Comment: If it is being used as part of an Intel Matrix Storage cache, it won't show up at all in the disk manager.  It appears that it plain isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

it's a fusion drive, two drives working as one logical unit. while it is possible to isolate them and use separately, that would involve a re-format of both volumes

fwiw, it looks like disk 0 is your hd and disk 1 your ssd. the hd has two primary partitioned volumes, C: and D:, while the ssd has only one primary, and a secondary (presumably scratch/vm) space

each OS has slightly different handling of fusion drives. it's a system level service (software) for most, but there are also hardware/firmware implementations of fusion devices. e.g. part of the RAM on a device could be used for fusion

Seagate (and therefore most other mfgs) calls their HDD/SSD combo a "hybrid" drive, presumably attempting to capitalize on the pervasiveness of "hybrid" engine cars being more efficient than normal

Comment: A [fusion drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive) is specific to Apple. Hybrid drives have the NAND flash embedded in the drive casing. ASUS (and others) are using a separate mSATA SSD card as the cache and not a hybrid drive.